# Prevent Absolute Div from Going Off Screen?

Tags: html, css

If I have an absolute positioned HTML object with

```
top: 50vh;
```

but then make the browser window really thin, the bottom of the object will go off screen starting at the bottom since the object starts at the center line of the screen. Is there a way that I could make it so if the bottom of the object touches the bottom of the screen, it will begin pushing upward to stay on screen?

Example of object:
https://jsfiddle.net/p0uow75r/

EDIT: Debugging details

To see what I mean, make the browser window really thin until the green square goes off the white part of the screen. What I want to happen is once the green touches the bottom, it'll start pushing upward as the user continues the make the window thinner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min()) function for conditional rendering like this.

Bottom of the page would be `top: calc(100vh - 100px)`

If `50vh` would put the element off-screen, then `100vh - 100px` will result in a smaller value. We can therefore use min() to put the element at the bottom if it would be off-screen.

```css
.middle-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: min(100vh - 100px, 50vh);
  right: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle-right">

</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I thought you couldn't use conditions for absolute values. I have no idea why. Thank you!